# Task Board - with rally built in Add Task

Tags: javascript, ruby, popup, rally

I wish to add more usability to the Task board, by adding Tasks.

I stumbled across several task boards in Git Hub.
The best one is

https://github.com/Pistos/Rally-Task-Board/blob/master/code.html

In this implementation there are 2 errors:

Line 187

```
html.push('<a href="/slm/tk/new.sp?cpoi=' + __PROJECT_OID__  + 'd&itemIndex=0&projectScopeUp=false&projectScopeDown=true&workProduct=' + value.ObjectID + '" target="task-window">add task</a>');
```

1. There is a type-o /slm/tk/new.sp?cpoi=' + **PROJECT_OID**  + 'd, The d should be after the cpoi I guess.
2. The major one is closing the task tab upon save and close button and refresh the view of the task board.

I don't know if Rally has a better way to open a task window, but I think it's more of an issue of closing a new tab/pop up for that button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good catch on the typo you found in the Task editor url for the code above. As for refreshing the Task Board after clicking Save or Save and Close from the standard Rally Task Editor window that is raised in the code you found, this isn't really possible. The Task Board is written using YUI, and the standard Rally Task Editor doesn't have any Javascript-accessible "hooks" that would allow you to setup listeners from the Task Board to initiate a redraw in response to a Save event in the standard Task Editor.

I've seen various customer "Enhanced Task Boards" that allow adding Tasks from the Story Card. However, they do so  without using the standard Rally Task Editor. Rather they raise a YUI-based editor window within the Javascript app by adding an Add Task function. Most of these are based off of the existing Edit Task `showEditor` function found starting on line 440 of the standard App Catalog Task Board:

https://github.com/RallyApps/TaskBoard/blob/master/deploy/App.html

The Enhanced Task Boards with Add Task buttons usually build an Add Task editor using a very similar function to what you see in showEditor. You could easily make a similar modification by developing a an addTaskEditor function of your own.